# what does cheatsheets.sheets_dir()[0] mean in python?

Tags: python-3.x

what does cheatsheets.sheets_dir()[0] mean in python?
*cheatsheets* look like a package name. But sheets_dir never declare before, what does sheets_dir come from?

Answer (score 1):

cheatsheets package has sheets_dir() function, which returns list, which first element is accessed.